# JPA mapping multiple tables @OneToOne relationship with same composite key fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, composite-key

This is a conceptional example, I'm looking for the best implementation solution.

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
TABLE_A
-------
SIREN
NDA

TABLE_B
-------
SIREN
NDA

TABLE_C
-------
SIREN
NDA
```

The 3 tables have the same couple SIREN/NDA, this couple is unique and I must navigate between tables using it.

What is the best practice for creating this entities? Using SIREN/NDA as `COMPOSITE KEY` object or should I create a technical PK ID?

Comment: http://www.objectdb.com/

Comment: Yes you can create the same composite key for all three entities and in your mapping choose differents join columns names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the SIREN/NDA attribute couple is unique, you should proceed by making the couple a composite primary key. The example you have given, has three tables with the same set of attributes. There are instances where we get these type of tables, especially in Representing Class Hierarchies in the database schema. There are two general approaches depending on the **disjointness** and **completeness** of the between the related entities.

### Overlapping vs. Disjoint (Disjointness)

**Disjoint** - There is no entity common to the subclasses

**Overlapping** - There is at least one entity common to the subclasses

### Full vs. Partial (Completeness)

**Full** - All the entities of the super class belong to at least one of
the subclasses. Also known as covering.

**Partial** - At least one of the entities of the super class doesn’t
belong to either of the subclasses.

### First Approach - For non-disjoint and non-complete class hierarchies

- create a table for each super class entity set
  according to normal entity set translation method.
- Create a table for each subclass entity set with a
  column for each of the attributes of that entity set
  plus one for each attributes of the primary key of
  the super class entity set
- This primary key from super class entity set is also
  used as the primary key for this new table

**For example,** suppose the following entities with the attributes. Primary key is in bolded style.

> Person  : [**SSN**, Name, Gender]
>
> Student : [**SSN**, Stu_ID, Dept, GPA]
>
> Employee : [**SSN**, E_ID, Company, Salary]

Here, `Student` and `Employee` entities are subclasses of `Person` and both `Student` and `Employee` subentities have `SSN` as a common attribute. So, they are non-disjoint. They are also non-complete because, there can be entries in `Person` superclass which doesn't belong to any of the two subclasses `Student` and `Employee`.

So here, we create a table for the superclass entity `Person` with `SSN` being the primary key. We also create tables for subclass entities `Student` and `Employee` with `SSN` being the primary key.

### Second Approach - For disjoint and complete class hierarchies

- Do not create a table for the super class entity set
- Create a table for each subclass entity set include all
  attributes of that subclass entity set and attributes of
  the superclass entity set

**For example,** suppose the following entities with the attributes. Primary key is in bolded style.

> Vehicle : [**Vehicle_Id**, Make, Price]
>
> MotorVehicle : [**Vehicle_Id**, Engine_cc, Fuel_economy]
>
> Bicycle : [**Bike_Id**, Cogs, Chainrings]

Here, `MotorVehicle` and `Bicycle` entities are subclasses of `MotorVehicle`. `Car` and `Bicycle` subentities doesn't have any overlapping attributes. So, they are disjoint. They are also complete because, every entry in `Vehicle` superclass must fall into either of the subclasses `MotorVehicle` or `Bicycle`

So here, we don't create a table for the superclass entity `Vehicle`. We only create tables for subclass entities `MotorVehicle` and `Bicycle` with `Vehicle_Id` and `Bike_Id` being the primary keys respectively. They both include the attributes from the superclass entity. So the two tables are as follows.

> MotorVehicle : [**Vehicle_Id**, Make, Price, Engine_cc, Fuel_economy]
>
> Bicycle : [**Vehicle_Id**, **Bike_Id**, Make, Price, Cogs, Chainrings]